# function session_destroy kills/doent kills the session array

Tags: php, session

here are 3 php scripts:
the first file where I set the session:

```
<?php session_start(); // store session data
$_SESSION["username"] = "joshmathews" ;
$_SESSION["name"] = "josh" ; ?>
```

the second script where I first output the code and then I destroy the session and then start the session again:

```
<?php session_start(); 
echo "<br>Username = " . $_SESSION["username"];
echo "<br> name= " . $_SESSION["name"] ;
echo "<br>" . session_id() ; 
//session_id(200) ; //
 session_destroy() ; 
echo "<br>Username = " . $_SESSION["username"]; 
echo "<br> name= " . $_SESSION["name"] ; 
echo "<br>" .session_id() ;
```

the third script where I only output the session array:

```
<?php 
session_start() ; 
echo $_SESSION['name'] ; 
echo "<br>" . session_id() ; ?>
```

now in the second script if I include the line where I change the session id I can still access the session array in the third code but if I exclude the change of the session id then I cant acess the session array in the third code. why??????

Comment: I don't think you can use session variables after destroying it in the second block..

Comment: only if I write session_start() after the session_destroy() then I cant use these variables. do you know why????

Comment: the question is not clear, have you tried using `session_regenerate_id()` instead of destroying and re-creating session?

Comment: is session_destroy similar to session_unset but the difference is that it also temporary destroys the session. and if afterwards there will be a request for a script that has the line session_start then the final result would be similar if instead of session_destroy i would have used session_unset

Comment: No, I meant that you are destroying and re-creating session for a different session id, instead, why not use `session_regenerate_id()`?

Answer (score 2):

Because when you call `session_id(200)` - it is changing your current session to another one and you're destroying a newly created session.

Read here more: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

> If id is specified, it will replace the current session id. session_id() needs to be called before session_start() for that purpose

Comment: ok I understood what youre saying. but I have a question If I am destroying the newly session, shouldn't it only erase the data and keep the id of the session. because when I didn't change the session id it destroyed the data of the session but the session id was saved.

Answer (score 0):

`session_id()` needs to be called BEFORE `session_start()` in order for the ID to be properly set.

See the [manual for `session_id()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) . Under the parameter `$id` it states this.

> If id is specified, it will replace the current session id. session_id() needs
> to be called before session_start() for that purpose.

Also when setting the `$id`, you should pass it as a string for uniformity purposes:

```
session_id('200');
```